# django-filter list of links

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm using django-filter's *ChoiceFilter* to generate a dropdown to filter results and it works great.

However a *dropdown* is not what I have in mind for the design, instead I would like to use a *list of links*, but I can't find if there is such a filter.

How can I have a list of links instead of a dropdown ?

**Current:**

[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

**filters.py**

```
class manufacturerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    manufacturer=django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['manufacturer'].extra['choices'] = [
            (wheel, wheel)
            for wheel in WheelItem.objects.values_list('manufacturer', flat=True).distinct()
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming across this I managed to achieve the desired effect using `LinkWidget`. This will render each option as a link, instead of a dropdown.

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/widgets.html#linkwidget

```
manufacturer=django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=[],widget = django_filters.widgets.LinkWidget)
```

[image]